$G$ solvable group of order $pm$ has subgroup of order $m$ when $\mathrm{gcd}(p,m) = 1$ and $P$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup with $N_G(P) = P$.
As mentioned in the title, the problem I'm looking to solve is:
Let $G$ be a solvable group of order $pm$ and $\mathrm{gcd}(p,m) = 1$. Let $P$  a Sylow $p$-subgroup with $N_G(P) = P$. Prove $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $m$.
I've shown that if $G$ has a subgroup of order $m$, it must be characteristic and consist of elements of $G$ with order not equal to $p$.
A sketch of my solution attempt via induction is as follows:
By solvability of $G$, there is $N \unlhd G$ such that $G /N \cong \mathbb{Z} / \ell\mathbb{Z}$ with $\ell$ a prime.
Then, if $\ell = p$ we are done.
If $\ell \ne p$ then $\ell \mid m$, and we seek to apply the induction hypothesis to $N$. $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$ and $N_N(P) = P$ so by the induction hypothesis there is $N_1 \unlhd N$ of order $m/\ell$.
If $\ell \nmid m/\ell$, then there is $x \in G \setminus N$ an element of order $\ell$. Since $N_1$ is characteristic in $N$, then $N_1\unlhd G$ and so $N_1 <x>$ is a normal subgroup of order $m$ in $G$.
Now is a problem: On the other hand, if $\ell \mid m/\ell$, I don't think I can conclude that there is $x \in G \setminus N$ an element of order $\ell$.
I've been suggested to consider a Sylow $\ell$ subgroup of $N$, but I'm unsure of what to do with it. I feel like I am close and have some ideas but I think a hint might help.

So you have $N_1$ a normal subgroup of order $m/\ell$ in $N$. As you have shown already, $N_1$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
Hint: Take $Q$ to be an $\ell$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. Prove that $N_1Q$ is a subgroup of $G$ with order $m$.
Note: the result is true without assuming that $G$ is solvable, by Burnside's transfer theorem. But the proof for solvable groups is much easier.

Why is $N_1Q$ normal in $G$?

In this setup, any subgroup of $G$ of order $m$ is necessarily characteristic and, hence, normal. Since $N_1$ is normal in $G$, then $N_1 Q$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $m$, meaning it is automatically normal.
